# How to change dataframe column values to blank by taking into account the length of those words in Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

How could I achieve this?

If a word's length is less than 3, replace those values with "blank.

| Words | Len | Expected OutPut |
| --- | --- | --- |
| TN27E8375 | 9 | TN27E8375 |
| - | **1** |  |
| DP - 2073698 | 12 | DP - 2073698 |
|  | **0** |  |
| New | 3 | New |
| *5 | **2** |  |

Comment: and… what is the logic?

Comment: This looks like a merge/map. Read the duplicate carefully and please provide a fully reproducible example of you don't manage to get it to work

Comment: This is not how it works. Please read again the help. You failed to provide a reproducible example (input+output, as code **not images**), the code that you used, a description of how it failed, and how the linked duplicate does not answer your question (in your case **all** are needed).

Comment: Your code is not formatted, not in a single block, one can not simple copy past a block and get everything running smoothly. Descriptions can help as **supplement**, not as primary source of code. Also the other concerns are not addressed (I believe the answer you want is in the duplicate, have you read it?)

Comment: Reopen my question now.

Comment: @mozway Kindly take action on my request.